# PostGIS function testing geometries, inside and boundary

Tags: postgis, function, boundaries

Is there a st_????(A geometry, B geometry) in PostGIS that returns *true* when B is inside A and **possibly** shares a boundary ?
I would say no after reading the doc but something may have escaped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ST_Relate](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html) can do that; you can specifically define the spatial relation you want by using the [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM).
A query would look like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
JOIN b
  ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
WHERE ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, 'TT*FT*FF*')
```

I made the matrix out of my head...you might need to alter it accordingly. Check out [this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/de9im.html) blog.

Comment: Sounds pretty good  after reading the blog. Thanks.